# Array out of bounds with string split

Tags: java, split

I'm reading from a text file, and setting parameters for my object (Dogs) to the information on the text file. It's a very simple task but I keep getting an array out of bounds error every time I try to access field[1] or field[2]. My code is as follows:

```
BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dogslist.txt"));
    String line  = inFile.readLine();
    int count = 0;
    Dogs[] parlour = new Dogs[16];

    while(line != null)
    {
    String[] field = line.split("#");
    int age = Integer.parseInt(field[2]);
    parlour[count] = new Dogs(field[0],field[1],age);
    System.out.println(parlour[count]);
    count++;
    line = inFile.readLine();
    }
```

Here are the contents of the text file:

```
Jerry#German Sheapord#4
Owen#cat#3
Morgan#MathsGenius#7
```

Text file of Error, textfile and code: http://pastebin.com/SznqE45i

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: so there is empty lines ?

Comment: There aren't any empty lines in the text file. The error is in the 9th line of the code here. (int age = Integer.parseInt(field[2]);)

Comment: @MorganBlem but when ? add `System.out.println("line : "+line);` and see the line.you can check length for safe .`if(field.length()>2)`

Comment: avoid using hard coded values like field[2] and so on. You can use Scanner to do some easy parsing

Comment: Based on the contents of the textfile you have shown us, there are empty lines between each valid line.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(line)` look like?

Comment: @pczeus the text file itself doesn't contain empty spaces, its just the way it formatted when I posted the question.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @brso05 when I print it the line it returns it accurately. If I use if(field.length>2) as the test with System.out.println(line); inside, the test passes and it spits out the lines as they are in the text file.

Comment: can you upload your text file to pastebin.com ?

Comment: @MorganBlem please post exactly what is in the console because if what you are saying is true then there is no problem and this question can be closed...

Comment: There has to be an empty line in your text  file

Comment: @MorganBlem take out the `if(field.length>2)`...what does it print when it fails?

Comment: Here is a text file containing: My text file, my full code, and my error. http://pastebin.com/SznqE45i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your problem by being more 'defensive' in your code and validating each input line has content and that your array after splitting is as expected:

```
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dogslist.txt"));
    String line;
    int count = 0;
    Dogs[] parlour = new Dogs[16];

    while((line = inFile.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.trim().length() > 0){
            String[] field = line.split("#");

            if(field.length < 3){
                System.out.println("Invalid line encountered: " + line);
            }
            else{
                int age = Integer.parseInt(field[2]);
                parlour[count] = new Dogs(field[0],field[1],age);
                System.out.println(parlour[count]);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked :) thank you for the help. If you could, would you mind telling me why mine didn't? The text file didn't have open lines so the trimming wasn't necessary, however other than that the code is extremely similar to that which I used.

Comment: I ran your original code and unless there was an empty line before the first valid line, it worked. There must be an empty line in the original file. Regardless, adding defensive code to protect against invalid input is always a good idea to save debugging time and produce more quality code.

Comment: I hunted down the error! Basically, the text file looked exactly as it should've but I think when I wrote it I used Shift + enter and then enter, which messed with the readLines, but since it was just a text file you cant see a difference